# An error is thrown in PROD mode but NOT in DEV mode: "Notice: Undefined index" in $form->getConfig()->getAttributes()

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, production-environment, symfony-3.2

Running my symfony3 project in the `prod` enviroment on an Ubuntu Server I get the following error:

> "Notice: Undefined index: data_collector/passed_options",

This error does not happen if I use the `dev` environment.

The error is thrown in my custom `FormType`:

```php
// src/MyBundle/Form/CustomType/MyCustomType.php:
class MyCustomType extends AbstractType {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
           $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event){....}
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $inheritedAttr = $form->getConfig()->getAttributes()['data_collector/passed_options']['attr']; //it crashes there
             ....   
      }

}
```

I edited my `app_dev.php` file on the production Ubuntu Server ([Like it is explained here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/forum/32/topic/41866.html)) so that I could test in production using this command:

php bin/console server:start [the IP of my server]:[a custom port]

But the error still didn't get thrown in the `dev` environment. So it's not a problem with my development machine.

Could it be that `$form->getConfig()->getAttributes()` has no index in the `prod` environment?

Is there some way I can debug errors like this that happen in the `prod` environment but not in the `dev` environment?

Comment: That line where it crashes doesn't even look like the correct way to implement code. What are you trying to do? Do you have a reference tutorial or code that you are following? If so, can you post the link? I've seen a few of your posts on Symfony, and you seem to be following and older standard rather than [the latest documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html).

Comment: @Alvin Bunk, thank you for your input, I follow the SYMFONY documentation as much as I can. The work that has been made on this documentation is great. Maybe I use older standard there and there because I find solutions to my problems on SO or anywhere else.  I won't go in the details of my final goal also I understand that knowing that could help you to guide me in other direction that could be relevant for me. But I am too advanced in my code, it works great in DEV mode, I just want it to work in PROD now. I cannot risk to redesign it all at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `addEventListener` the `$options` that is passed as a parameter in the `buildForm` function should be passed as it contains the attributes:

```
class MyCustomType extends AbstractType {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
           $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($options) {....}
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $inheritedAttr = $options['attr'];
             ....   
      }

}
```